# How do I control an sd card reader using spidev

Tags: linux, usb, udev

I've got a Samsung RF711 Core i7 laptop running Debian Wheezy with an integrated usb Multi Flash Reader, but this question could apply to any system with an sd card reader on an usb port.
Here's what lsusb says

> Bus 004 Device 004: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader

I want to use an old sd card and solder some wires onto it to allow it to communicate with a PIC via SPI when I plug it into the sd card port.

I'm aware that the sd card voltages are 3.3v and that a voltage level converter would be needed to interface with a 5v SPI device.

I compiled a custom kernel to produce the spidev kernel module, now what?
I know it's something to do with udev rules, usb_modeswitch? but I can't see the wood for the trees.

Ideally the solution would be a program, let's call it sdcard-spi.
When the program starts it flips the drivers and creates an spidev device in /dev.
When it quits it restores the slot functionality to be able to read sdcards once more.
It could be a daemon process - starting it converts the slot, stopping it converts the slot back to being an sd card reader.

It seems like something the writers of spidev could easily do, as sd cards are initially probed in SPI mode.

Just to be clear, I want to open the sd card reader in SPI mode, so no card is detected and I can do SPI communication using an spidev device node, say /dev/spidev.0.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this by writing a linux driver.

You would have to rewrite the firmware of the card reader.  There's a synchronous serial interface inside the card reader, but the interface between card reader and Linux computer is not a general purpose serial interface, but a USB mass-storage device.

Comment: Er, nope. There's no mass storage device until you put an sd card into the slot, at which point udev rules spring to life and create device node(s) for the partitions on the sd card.

Comment: @PhilipAshmore: Actually, it reports as mass storage device profile, but with a status of media-not-present.  Not that there would be any difference if the device didn't enumerate without a card present.  You still can't send arbitrary SPI transfers, only USB mass-storage commands which are decoded by the reader firmware.

Comment: Pic USB devices (http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en-us/technology/usb/home.html) can "talk" spi to sd cards so I could just use one of them (I've got 3 PIC18F14K50-I/P samples on their way). The linux kernel matches a device ID to a kernel module, so different udev rules would hold off matching the device with usb_storage, specifying it as a device the spidev module can use.

Comment: The other aspect of this to consider is device trees (http://www.devicetree.org/Main_Page), but I don't know enough to proceed.

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm talking about changing how the kernel recognizes the sd card READER, not an sd card inserted into the reader. It's got pins, like the above-mentioned PICs and when an sd card is inserted it uses SPI to negotiate a faster communications mode with the card.

Comment: @philip: You just don't get it, do you?  You cannot use `spidev` with your reader, because the reader doesn't accept SPI configuration commands.  Only USB mass storage commands.  You can't access the memory-mapped I/O registers inside the reader from the Linux kernel on the host PC.  Only the firmware on the reader's own processor has that level of access.

Comment: I guess I was hoping the sd card reader was something like a PIC, but yeah, even then, if it's not set up to allow SPI to it's pins then it isn't possible. I was hoping that the protocol negotiation along with the protocol switches were done by the kernel module. lsusb reports my device as a "Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader" but that device is only present when I have an sd card in the slot, so something's adding it and removing it.